# text area validation not working in javascript php

Tags: javascript, php, validation

Im trying to validate text area in javascript.

here is the php code

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo "hello";
}
?>
```

here is the javascript code :

```
<script>
function formValidation()
{
    var usermessage = document.forms["frm_contact"]["userMsg"].value;
    if(usermessage === '')
    {
      alert("hello");
       document.getElementById('userMsg').focus();
       return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

here is the html code :

```
 <form method="post" id="frm_contact" action="" onSubmit="return formValidation();">
     <textarea name="userMsg" id="userMsg"><?= $_POST['userMsg'] ?> </textarea>
<input type="submit" value="check value" name="submit" onclick="return checkmessage();">
</form>
```

When i click on submit the form is not validating in javascript. Not able to find the issue. But the same code if working for `<input type='text' name='userMsg'>`

Comment: check if its targetting the input correctly, try console.log(usermessage);

Comment: `textarea` value should not be in `value` attribute but inserted as regular text between the tags like: `<textarea><?php echo $_POST['userMsg'];?></textarea>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `textarea` is placed between tags like this:

```
<textarea name="..."> value </textarea>
```

So, you could change here:

```
<textarea name="userMsg" id="userMsg" value="<?= $_POST['userMsg'] ?>"> </textarea>
```

To

```
<textarea name="userMsg" id="userMsg" > <?= $_POST['userMsg'] ?></textarea>
```

And, I guess you could remove `onclick="return checkmessage();"` if you don't use it.

Your code could go like this:

```
<form method="post" id="frm_contact" action="" onSubmit="return formValidation();">
    <textarea name="userMsg" id="userMsg"><?= $_POST['userMsg'] ?> </textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="check value" name="submit">
</form>
```

Hope this helps:

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. It will work.

```
<script>
function formValidation()
{

alert("hello");
    var usermessage = document.forms["frm_contact"]["userMsg"].value;
    if(usermessage=='')
    {
      alert("hello");
       document.getElementById('userMsg').focus();
       return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
 <form method="post" id="frm_contact" name="frm_contact" action="" onSubmit="return formValidation();">
     <textarea name="userMsg" id="userMsg"><?= $_POST['userMsg'] ?></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="check value" name="submit" >
</form>
```

You have to set the form name to "frm_contact" not the id for using

```
document.forms['form_name']['element_name'].value;
```

Comment: I was the one who answered you correctly. But you marked as the right answer for the same answer provided by another geek who posted minutes later. :P

Comment: sorry buddy.. i was in hurry. and the thing which i have done wrong is in text area i have take attribute value='$_POST['name']' which is wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to made `two` changes

**1.** change textarea like this because textarea hasn't any `value` tag.

```
<textarea name="userMsg" id="userMsg"><?= $_POST['userMsg'] ?>"></textarea>
```

**2.** is `JS function` because if you left some white spaces only the codition will not check and textarea looks like blank so use `trim`

```
var usermessage = document.forms["frm_contact"]["userMsg"].value;
usermessage =  usermessage.trim(); // include this for remove whitespaces
if(usermessage == '')
{
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the **`space`** between textarea open tag and close tag. use like this

```
<textarea name="userMsg" id="userMsg"><?=$_POST['userMsg'];?></textarea>
```

not like this

```
<textarea name="userMsg" id="userMsg"><?=$_POST['userMsg'];?> </textarea>
```

**Complete Code:**

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo 'Your input is: '.$_POST['userMsg'];
}
?>
<script>
function formValidation() {
    var usermessage = document.forms["frm_contact"]["userMsg"].value;
    if (usermessage === '') {
        alert('Error: You missed the field');
        document.getElementById('userMsg').focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
<form method="post" id="frm_contact" action="" onSubmit="return formValidation();">
     <textarea name="userMsg" id="userMsg"><?php echo $_POST['userMsg']; ?></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="check value" name="submit" onclick="return checkmessage();">
</form>
```

**Reason Why your code not working:**

You are validating textarea in javascript with no space

```
if (usermessage === '')
```

and your textarea has a space :) so, this is the reason your code is not working :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    hope this will help
   <script>
   function formValidation()
   {
   var usermessage = document.forms["frm_contact"]["userMsg"].value;
   if(usermessage === '')
   {
   alert("hello");
   document.getElementById('userMsg').focus();
   return false;
   }
   else
    {
    return true;
   }
   }
   </script>



   <?php


   $usermsg=$_POST['userMsg'];

   ?>



   <form method="post" id="frm_contact" action="" onSubmit="return formValidation();">

   <textarea name="userMsg" id="userMsg"><?php if(isset($usermsg)){echo $usermsg;}?>     
  </textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="check value" name="submit" onclick="return    
   checkmessage();">
  </form>
```